# OpenCV: Multiple Cameras and Correspondences To Get 3D

Tags: python, c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I have `N` calibrated cameras. Their external matrix is in respect to a common reference frame. I have 2D points in each camera and I know their correspondence. How can I get the 3D points using OpenCV?

Comment: What do you mean by "I have 2D points in each camera and I know their correspondence". For a specific 2D point in one image camera, you can have the corresponding 2D point in the other cameras? If yes, it looks like you need a triangulation method like in stereo camera case. There is a function in OpenCV for triangulation but it works on undistorted and rectified image I think.

Comment: @Catree that's what I mean. there should be a function to do this without rectified images no?